# Missing ActionValidatorManagerFactory In Struts 2.2.3?

Tags: struts2

Has ActionValidatorManagerFactory been replaced in Struts 2.2.3? I'm trying to write a unit test to test my validation logic, and can't find the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it was removed some time ago in favor of a dependency injection approach.

This may help you out:

http://www.mail-archive.com/dev@struts.apache.org/msg31637.html

Comment: So, I can't unit test a Struts2 action outside of a container... great. Thanks for the response.